# Root of MAPE in forecasting

Tags: python, forecasting

> Can I get the root of Mean Absolute Percentage Error (MAPE) to avoid exceeding in 100%?
> I am working with forecasting of production, then I'm getting a large error that's why I my percentage of accuracy is exceeding in 100%.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're searching for a way to deceive others about the performance of your model? ;)

Comment: @artemis No I just want to know if there's other way to limit the percentage to 100%. Because I want a nice and appropriate number of percentage for my client. But I know it's normal to exceed in 100% in terms of forecasting, but thankyou :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I've understood your issue but if you want the MAPE to be under 100 the root of the MAPE won't garantee it. I propose to standardise your MAPE by applying :

```
sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler
```

Then you will have number between 1 and 0 and if you you multiply by 100 you will have a metric between 0 and 100 even if it's not a percentage. After, I would prefer RMSE for regression metrics.